# Почему Undefined variable: sol?

Tags: php

```
function merge($first, $second)
{
    $sol = function ($left, $right, $res) use ($first, $second) {
        if ($left >= count($first) && $right >= count($second)) {
            return $res;
        }
        if ($right >= count($second) || $first[$left] <= $second[$right]) {
            return $sol($left + 1, $right, $res[] = $first[$left]);
        } else {
            return $sol($left, $right + 1, $res[] = $second[$right]);
        } 
    };
    return $sol(0, 0, array());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Потому что `$sol` это переменная, которая определена в функции merge и замыкание о ней ничего не знает. Нужно передать в замыкание информацию об этой переменной. Но для этого ее нужно вначале объявить

```
 $sol = null;
 $sol = function ($left, $right, $res) use ($first, $second, $sol) {
```

Comment: Спасибо за овет, но по прежнему выбивает ту же ошибку.

Comment: @dimon Изменил ответ